# Bug - Files:patch don't change labels.hidden parameter any more

Tags: google-drive-api

Recently, Google Drive API's "Files:patch" command has stopped updating labels.hidden parameter.

The problem can be reproduced using Google APIs Explorer console.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch

How to reproduce is below.

1. Set "labels.hidden" and "labels.starred" as checked in "patch body" input form.
2. Set "id" and "labels" in "field" input form.
3. Click "Execute" button.

The Request and Response shown in APIs Expolorer is,

**Request**

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{FILE-ID}?fields=id%2Clabels
&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  .......
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "labels": {
  "hidden": true,
  "starred": true
 }
}
```

**Response**

```
200 OK

{
 "id": "{FILE-ID}",
 "labels": {
  "starred": true,
  "hidden": false,
  "trashed": false,
  "restricted": false,
  "viewed": true
 }
}
```

As shown above, although starred state changed to true, hidden state stays false after executing "Files:patch".

The same problem occurs with "Files:update". However, with "Files:insert", labels.hidden parameter works.

Could anybody look into the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the description of `labels.hidden` in the [Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files). `labels.hidden` is deprecated.

Comment: so it is. 
Does anybody know (a) when it became deprecated, (b) where the deprecation was announced, and (c) what is the timescale for its withdrawal?

Comment: I didn't know it is deprecated. Thank you.

Comment: @pinoyyid: I also would like to know these deprecation infos. Especially, the announcement.